# Using C or C++ to write a Linux shell

Tags: c++, c, linux, shell, programming-languages

I need to write a Linux shell for a school project. We can use C or C++. I am a little more comfortable with C++, and since I'm working with a partner, the object-oriented aspect of it is helpful. However, I suspect that for some reason C is better, and that most if not all Linux shells are written in C and not C++. What are the pros and cons of using one or the other?

Comment: for a project like this, i'm inclined to say whichever you are more comfortable with

Comment: This is a pretty subjective question, as you should use whatever you and your partner are most comfortable with. One reason for why almost all (if not all) Unix/Linux shells are written in C is because POSIX-compliant systems guarantee the existence of a libc (standard C library) on the system (and because many shells are based on older shells written in original Unix era), whereas there is no guarantee for a standard C++ library necessary to run compiled C++ code.

Comment: The reason most Linux shells are written in C is because they were written years ago, before C++ was popular or even existed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the only difference I'd say is the dependency on libstd-c++ if you end up using STL and stuff. Plain C implementation if done correctly will run on bare minimum system requirements (libc only)